# How to find whether to single insert or delete from a string would make two strings equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image] Write a function named `single_insert_or_delete` that accepts two
strings as input arguments and returns:

- `0` if the two strings match exactly.
- `1` if the first string can become the same as the second string by
  inserting or deleting a single character. Notice that inserting and
  deleting a character is not the same as replacing a character.
- `2` otherwise.

Capital letters are considered the same as lower case letters.

**The code:**

```
def single_insert_or_delete (input_str, input_str_1):
    str_1 = input_str.lower()
    str_2 = input_str_1.lower()
    if (str_1 == str_2):
        return 0

#Main Program
input_str = input("Enter a string 1: ")
input_str_1 = input("Enter a string 2: ")
result = single_insert_or_delete(input_str, input_str_1)
print(result)
```

**My question here is:** How to proceed further for checking whether to insert or delete the character or do both?

From my analysis we have to check first whether the words are equal in length and then go for checking the character of the words. But then how to go about if the lengths of the string do not match?

These are some examples in the above image.

Comment: If the lengths do not match, find the first character that is different.  If adding the correct letter makes the whole string match, it is a match.  If removing the incorrect letter makes the whole string match, it is a match.  Otherwise, it is not a match.

Comment: Did the teacher not go through the problem in class? I guess they are asking you to implement the string matching algorithm, which is usually solved with dynamic programming.

Comment: I wonder why basically [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=single_insert_or_delete) has been asked repeatedly over the last couple of hours). Does that same teacher refer all the students to SO? :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Almost certainly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can't add a comment I will post here the answer.

```
def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    s1,s2 = s1.lower(), s2.lower()
    count = 0
    if s1 == s2:
        return 0
    elif len(s1) == len(s2):
        return 2
    elif len(s1) - len(s2) == -1:
        if s1 == s2[:-1]:
            return 1
        else:
            for i in range(len(s2)):
                if s1 == s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]:
                    return 1
            else:
               return 2
    elif len(s1) - len(s2) == 1:
        if s1[:-1] == s2 or s1[1:] == s2:
            return 1
        else:
            for i in range(len(s1)):
                if s2 == s1[:i] + s1[i+1:]:
                    return 1
            else:
                 return 2  

    else:
        return 2
```

Comment: @Dingo, I have updated the code, now should work with the reversed strings: s1 is programming and s2 is programing

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
>>> def f(s1, s2):
        s1, s2 = s1.lower(), s2.lower()
        if s1 == s2:
            return 0
        elif len(s1) == len(s2):
            return 2
        elif len(s1) - len(s2) == 1:
            if (s1[1:] == s2) or (s1[:-1] == s2):
                return 1
        elif len(s1) - len(s2) == -1:
            #skip one char from s2 and check if it matches s1
            for i in range(len(s2)):
                if s1 == s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]:
                     return 1
        else:
            return 2

>>> f('python', 'java')
2
>>> 
>>> f('book', 'boot')
2
>>> f('sin', 'sink')
1
>>> 
>>> f('dog', 'dog')
0
>>> 
>>> f('poke', 'spoke')
1
>>> 
>>> f('poker', 'poke')
1
>>> 
>>> f('programing', 'programming')
1
```

Basically,

1. Checks if s1 and s2 are same, then return 0
2. If not, then    check if they have same lengths, meaning to get
   them equals, we need    a replacement, which should return 2
3. If their lengths is    just one character difference, then we
   can either delete or insert or    character depending which one is
   greater than the other.

Comment: this function returns none for the strings "sin" and "sink"

Comment: Please update your code there is some problem when I enter "poke" and "poker" as two strings.

Comment: @KaranThakkar .. Do accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def inner_rearrange_string(s1,s2):
    answer=2  # returns 2 by default
    #Jump one char from s2 and check if it matches s1
    for i in range(1,len(s2)-1):
        if s1 == s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]:
            answer=1
    return answer

def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    s1, s2 = s1.lower(), s2.lower()
    lent=len(s2)
    s1_lent=len(s1)
    number_of_mismatch=0 #Get the current number of mismatch
    if s1 == s2:
        return 0
    elif len(s1) == len(s2): #Are the lengths equal? 
        for c in range (0,len(s1)):
            if s1[c]==s2[c]:
                Ismatch=True
            else:
                Ismatch=False
                number_of_mismatch+=1 # Increment the number of mismatch character(s)
        if(number_of_mismatch==1):
            return 1                    # return 1 then
        elif number_of_mismatch>=2:
            return 2                    # return 2 then
    elif len(s1) - len(s2) == 1:   # Is s1 > s2
        if (s1[1:] == s2) or (s1[:-1] == s2):
            return 1
    elif len(s1) - len(s2) == -1:  # Is s1 < s2
        if(s1==s2[1:lent]) or (s1==s2[0:lent-1]):
            return 1
        elif inner_rearrange_string(s1,s2)==1:  # call another function
            return 1
        else:
            return 2

    else:
        return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is wrong tho when:

single_insert_or_delete('the', 'that')
The function returns:None (instead of 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
def _instructor_function (s1,s2):
    s1=s1.lower()
    s2=s2.lower()
    if s1==s2:
        return 0
    if abs(len(s1)-len(s2))!=1:
        return 2

    if len(s1)>len(s2):
        # only deletion is possible
        for k in range(len(s2)):
            if s1[k]!=s2[k]:
                if s1[k+1:]==s2[k:]:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 2
        return 1
    else: # s1 is shorter Only insertion is possible
        for k in range(len(s1)):
            if s1[k]!=s2[k]:
                if s1[k:]==s2[k+1:]:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 2
        return 1
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more your answer so others can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    # Making str1 as the smaller string
    if len(s1) <= len(s2):
        str1 = s1.lower()
        str2 = s2.lower()
    else:
        str1 = s2.lower()
        str2 = s1.lower()
    if str1 == str2:
        return 0
    l1 = len(str1)
    l2 = len(str2)

    if l1 == l2:
        return 2
    else:
        i = 0
        flag = 0
        for j in str2:
            if str1[i] == j:
                i = i + 1
            else:
                flag = flag + 1

    if flag == 1:
        return 1
else:
    return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit outdated, you might be interested in checking 'Levenshtein distance'. What you want can be derived when Levenshtein distance of two given strings is calculated. 
https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/

If you just want to get the result, you can use a package like [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all char in smaller string from bigger string and calculate the length of remain string. if the length of remain string is equal 1 you can delete a char to make equal the two string

```
enter code here
def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
 lower_s1=s1.lower()
 lower_s2=s2.lower()
 a=len(s1)
 b=len(s2)
 s3=''

 if a==b :
      if lower_s1== lower_s2 :
           return 0
      else :
           return 2
 elif a-b==1 :
      s3=lower_s1
      for item in lower_s2 :
           s3=s3.replace(item , '' ,1)
      if len (s3)==1 :
           return 1
      else :
           return 2
 elif b-a==1 :
      s3=lower_s2
      for item in lower_s1 :
           s3=s3.replace(item , '' , 1)
      if len (s3)==1 :
           return 1
      else :
           return 2
 else :
      return 2
```